# Return a map from a list of values in Clojure

Tags: clojure

How would you put values from a list or vector into a map?

I do it the following way but it does not seem simple:

```
user=> (into {} (map #(into [] %) (partition 2 [1 2 3 4 5 6])))
{1 2, 3 4, 5 6}
user=>
```

Or if I wanted to also deal with an odd number of values (although possibly not worthwhile, but perhaps to preserve keys):

```
user=> (into {} (map #(if (even? (count %))
  #_=>                  (into [] %)
  #_=>                  [(first %) nil])
  #_=>               (partition-all 2 [1 2 3 4 5])))
{1 2, 3 4, 5 nil}
user=>
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: The first one can be done with `(apply hash-map [1 2 3 4 5 6])`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks @Tomo. I suppose using your advice I can achieve the second one with something like `(apply hash-map (let [a [1 2 3 4 5]] (if (odd? (count a)) (conj a nil) a)))`. Feel free to put it in answer format.

Comment: Let's see if anybody smarter than me can answer it better. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below function should take care of both cases (assuming a Vector is passed as an argument to to-map):

```
(defn to-map [v]
  (apply hash-map
         (if (odd? (count v))
           (conj v nil)
           v)))
```

Answer (score 3):

An allergic-to-conditionals version, tested for vectors and lists, even and odd.

```
(defn seq->map
  [s]
  (let [s+ (concat s [nil])]
    (zipmap (take-nth 2 s+)
            (take-nth 2 (rest s+)))))

(seq->map '(1 2 3 4))   ; {3 4, 1 2}
(seq->map '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; {5 nil, 3 4, 1 2}
(seq->map [1 2 3 4])    ; {3 4, 1 2}
(seq->map [1 2 3 4 5])  ; {5 nil, 3 4, 1 2}
```